# What does the @ means in ip link show command?

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I am new to Linux network admin. I was learning the ip commands with one of my colleague's server with ip link command.

When I try to show to one of the vlan information, I see this:

```
vlan1@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
link/ether 00:0c:29:87:89:8a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 1 
vlan protocol 802.1Q id 1 <REORDER_HDR>
```

I am confused with the "@" and the "master br1". So does it means the vlan is attached on eth1 or on br1?

eth1 is the outgoing interface while br1 is just an internal linux bridge.

Thanks.

Comment: "I was playing around with one of my colleague's server" Statements like this give me heart palpitations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My colleague told me I can do anything with it as it is a testing VM. I changed my description. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't really provided us with enough information to accurately answer the question, but I can make some guesses.

It sounds like `vlan1@eth1` is a VLAN interface (for VLAN ID 1) over `eth1` (that is, `eth1` is trunking at least one VLAN).  This `vlan1@eth1` interface is then attached to bridge `br1`.  If that device is a standard Linux bridge, you should be able to confirm this with the `brctl` command, which produces output like this:

```
# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br-em1      8000.3c970ebf6dce   no      em1
virbr0      8000.52540009c22a   yes     virbr0-nic
```

A good way to verify this would be to look at the persistent network configuration.  In a Red Hat derived system, this will be in files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, and for a Debian-ish system (including Ubuntu), this will often be in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

In general, the `@` in an interface name is used to denote a virtual interface associated with another interface.  You will also see this used for [macvlan](http://www.pocketnix.org/posts/Linux%20Networking:%20MAC%20VLANs%20and%20Virtual%20Ethernets) devices and  [ipip](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.tunnel.ip-ip.html) tunnels.